# Manejar turnos con laravel

Tags: laravel

[image: Tabla turnos]
[image]

- En el campo no confirmado recibe el valor del campo status cero, al momento de guardar  me genera el numero 99 en el campo turno que esto quiere decir en lista de espera
- Aqui me genera el numero 99, pero cuando quiero actualizar el status a 1 que es que el paciente puede pasar a consulta no me funciona, quiero un contador, que se actualize a cero todos los dias segun la fecha. POSD reemplaze el codigo seria muy amable si alguien me puede ayudar

Tengo esto mi controlador

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    if ($request->status == 0) {

        $turno = 99;
    } else {

        //
    }

    $turnoNew = new Turno;
    $turnoNew->medico_id = $request->medico_id;
    $turnoNew->paciente_id = $request->paciente_id;
    $turnoNew->fecha = $request->fecha;
    $turnoNew->status = $request->status;
    $turnoNew->turno = $turno;
    $turnoNew->save();
    return redirect()->route('citas.index');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Buenas amigo debe iniciar $turno =0; o en el else

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    if ($request->status == 0) {

        $turno = 99;
    } else {

        $turno = 0;
    }

    $turnoNew = new Turno;
    $turnoNew->medico_id = $request->medico_id;
    $turnoNew->paciente_id = $request->paciente_id;
    $turnoNew->fecha = $request->fecha;
    $turnoNew->status = $request->status;
    $turnoNew->turno = $turno;
    $turnoNew->save();
    return redirect()->route('citas.index');
}
```

y para tu contador que diario cambie a 0 necesitas crear una ruta y una función y usas WhereDate a partir de la fecha actual ejemplo $fecha_actual=date('Y-m-d'); y esto lo comparas con el created_ad ejemplo

$resultados=Modelo::WhereDate('created_ad','>=',$fecha_actual)->get();

luego recorres con un foreach $resultados y actualizas el turno a cero y aplicas el save();

por ultimo la función la terminas con un return true, y creas un cronjod apuntando a tu ruta que se ejecute a diario.